# "edit top 200 rows" not available via context menu in ssms for system-versioned tables?

Tags: sql-server

I just set SYSTEM_VERSIONING=ON for SS DB table. "(System-Versioned)" now displays to the right of the table name.  However, it appears that I can no longer have the "Edit Top 200 Rows" context menu option on this table. I'm using SSMS v17.4.  Is this a known issue or constraint with SSMS when using system-versioned tables?  Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using that "feature" anyway. It has been known to cause random issues for a LONG time. It is far better to get comfortable with an update statement and write it instead of directly editing the data.

Comment: The "Select Top 1000 Rows" context menu option doesn't display either

Comment: So just learn to write a select query in SSMS.

Comment: doesn't bother me but I've been asked to present this to my organization.  some devs may not like the fact that it impacts their ide

Comment: Is the "Script Table as..." option still present in the context menu?

Comment: wow even the "Design" context menu option goes away for system-versioned tables in ssms.  I wonder if microsoft removed this functionality for a reason or if microsoft simply hasn't gotten around to implementing designer support for this yet?

Comment: Only thing I find is this:   https://serverfault.com/questions/867871/ssms-context-menu-on-temporal-system-versioned-table-doesnt-show-table-action?rq=1  You should open a connect ticket and at least get Microsoft to document this behavior.

Comment: @TabAlleman - the only items in my context menu are Reports, Rename and Refresh

Comment: I'm reporting this issue based on the express versions of ss and ssms installed on my local laptop.  I'm still waiting on local admin rights in order to install ss on my work pc.  can someone here verify if they see the context menus on their paid version of ss/ssms?

Comment: @user9393635 I have the exact same problem SSMS 2017 V17.7

Comment: this works in Visual Studio - SQL Server Explorer